# Implementation of arbitrary argument order construction call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I am new to angular/js/ts and I am trying to figure out how Dependency Injection works in angular.

Up to this point a lot of things are clear but I don't understand how angular can call the component constructor, and injecting the dependencies, without knowing the order in which they are defined in the constructor definition.

Just to have a context. Take this simple modification of the [Angular.io getting started example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vz9whe).

When I define the constructor of the component `product-list.component.ts` I can use these two constructor definition and everything works.

```
//definition 1
constructor(s2: S2Service, s1: S1Service){
    s1.log();
    s2.log();
  }
```

```
//definition 2
constructor(s1: S1Service, s2: S2Service){
    s1.log();
    s2.log();
  }
```

How does the framework knows the order in which I define the component's constructor ?
How does Angular calls this constructor ?

If you want an even simpler example.
Let's assume we want to define a class with a constructor that takes 4 arguments (with 4 different types). How do we write the constructor so that can take the 4 arguments in every possible order without defining multiples (24?(not sure)?) constructor definitions, and  without using named arguments or some sort of object encapsulation , just as the Angular framework does ?

Answer (score 0):

By the types. It takes the type to inject and looks for that type in the constructor args.

Comment: Ok, but how do you check the type of an object's constructor ? do you parse the .ts file as text file? how can you check the type of an object at run time ?

Comment: Dig into the code in Angular source. But, if you look at the prototype of a class, you will see the constructor and it’s args. I’m not sure JS provides trrue reflection, but you can certainly look at a type before creating an instance of it. By parsing out modules in an app, you get all the types (you have declared, provided, etc). So getting a list of types parsed out before any are created is probably pretty straightforward. In fact this is probably a core operation of TS.